# Sorting a hash table of objects (by the attributes of the objects) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, object, hash, attributes

Say I have a class called Person, and it contains things such as last name, first name, address, etc.

I also have a hash table of Person objects that needs to be sorted by last and first name.
I understand that a sort_by will not change the hash permanently, which is fine, I only need to print in that order.  Currently, I am trying to sort/print in place using:

```
@hash.sort_by {|a,b| a <=> b}.each { |person| puts person.last}
```

I have overloaded the <=> operator to sort by last/first, but nothing appears to actually sort.  The puts there simply outputs in the hash's original order.  I have spent a good 4 days trying to figure this out (it is a school assignment, and my first Ruby program).  Any ideas?  I am sure this is easy, but I am having the hardest time bringing my brain out of the C++ way of thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be confusing `sort` and `sort_by`

`sort` yields two objects from the collection to the block and expects you to return a <=> like value: -1,0 or 1 depending on whether the arguments are equal, ascending or descending, for example

```
%w(one two three four five).sort {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}
```

Sorts the strings by length. This is the form to use if you want to use your <=> operator

`sort_by` yields one object from the collection at a time and expects you to return what you want to sort by - you shouldn't be doing any comparison here. Ruby then uses <=> on these objecfs to sort your collection. The previous example can e rewritten as

```
%w(one two three four five).sort_by {|s| s.length}
```

This is also known as a [schwartzian transform](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

In your case the collection is a hash so things are slightly more complicated: the values that are passed into the block are arrays that contain key/value pairs, so you'll need to extract the person object from that pair. You could also just work on @hash.keys or @hash.values (depending on whether the person objects are keys or values)

Comment: Learning things like a Schwartzian transform make me a happy guy.  I got it now, and I am about to turn it in.  Thank you so much for the help and great post.

Answer (score 3):

If you've overidden the <=> operator to sort Person objects appropriately then you can simply do:

```
@hash.sort_by{ |key, person| person }
```

because sort_by will yield both the hash key, and the object (in your case a person) to each iteration of the block. So the code above will sort your hash based on Person objects - for which you've already specified an <=> operator.

Answer (score 0):

When you `#.sort_by` with a Hash, the parameters passed to the block are 'key','value', not 'element a' and 'element b'. Try:

```
@hash.sort_by{|key,value| value.last}.each{|key,value| puts value.last}
```

Also, see Frederick Cheung's excellent explanation of `#sort` vs `#sort_by`.