# problems with simple sorting of hashes in array being ignored

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have a simple array

```
my_array = [{id:1,priority_score:2},{id:3,priority_score:5},{id:4,priority_score:3.5}...]
```

I am trying to sort by the priority score with

```
sort_array = my_array.sort_by{|priority| priority[:priority_score]}
```

strangely, I am not getting a back any difference from my original array.

I create the priority score using

```
new_hash = {id:h.id,priority_score:(a.score+b.score)/2}
```

and have added all sorts of `.to_f`,`.to_i` in case the problem was that the priority score was not being recognized as a number, but that isn't the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're confusing sort and sort_by - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104273/sorting-a-hash-table-of-objects-by-the-attributes-of-the-objects-in-ruby/9104425#9104425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `sort_by` like this.

```
my_array.sort_by {|(h, _)| h[:priority_score]}
# [{:id=>1, :priority_score=>2}, {:id=>4, :priority_score=>3.5}, {:id=>3, :priority_score=>5}]
```

Comment: I haven't seen the `_` before, what is that for? (I left the office, so i can't actually check this until tomorrow).

Comment: `_` means not caring value. `a, _ = [10, 20]` it will set `a` to `10`.

Comment: @pedalpete I reexamined my answer and it is wrong. edu's solution is correct. `my_array.sort_by {|h| h[:priority_score]}` and my solution same thing. may you remove accept I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array#sort` method takes a block with two arguments, a and b, and wants you to compare them by hand.  Given how you invoke it, I think you wanted `sort_by`, which takes a block with each item in the array, performs some transformation, and sorts by the result.

Comment: thanks Daniel, I typed it wrong, i am using `sort_by`, corrected my question now. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The sort gets two elements and the sorting is done by the comparison result of these elements.

This comparison should return -1, 0, 1.

0 for equal, -1  first < second and +1 first > second.

In most of the cases you can use ruby built in function <=>

For example:

```
my_array = [{id:1,priority_score:2},{id:3,priority_score:5},{id:4,priority_score:3.5}]

# Sort ascending  
cr = my_array.sort {|a,b| a[:priority_score] <=> b[:priority_score]}
#[{:id=>1, :priority_score=>2}, {:id=>4, :priority_score=>3.5}, {:id=>3, :priority_score=>5}]

# Sort descending
de = my_array.sort {|a,b| b[:priority_score] <=> a[:priority_score]}
#[{:id=>3, :priority_score=>5}, {:id=>4, :priority_score=>3.5}, {:id=>1, :priority_score=>2}]
```

Comment: thanks Edu, I typed the question wrong, I am using `sort_by`. sorry for the confusion, but thanks for explaining this so clearly.